# I have an request data action in nintex workflow, am unable to configure that action

Tags: nintex-workflow

I have an request data action in nintex workflow, am unable to configure that action because of the disability of the ribbon which consist action,task reminder etc. how can i configure that action or is there any replacement for that action.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a browser other than IE it can cause this effect. 
I've just had the same issue when trying to edit the Nintex workflow in Firefox. 
When I switched to IE it worked ok and was once again editable.
I hope that this helps you.